# Use 2 Slider inputs to generate a Rectangle (Canvas). On new Inputs, delete the Rectangle

Tags: javascript, typescript, canvas, rectangles

I have 2 slider in my HTML that get me the desired Width and Height of the Rectangle they wanna do in my Canvas. It's working fine but i can't figure out how to delete the one Rectangle that i got before. I tried it with a boolean Value, but it gets messed up because both sliders are in the same Function, so when i move one of those sliders i cant move the other.

Here is my Function to draw the Rectangle:

```
function drawBackgroundBig(): void {
    if (canvasSet == false) {
        let newHeight: number = parseInt(heightSlider.value);
        // console.log(heightSlider.value);
        
        let newWidth: number = parseInt(widthSlider.value);
        // console.log(widthSlider.value);

        crc2.fillStyle = "red";
        crc2.fillRect(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
        crc2.stroke();
        crc2.save();
        newHeight = height;
        newWidth = width;
    }
    else {
        crc2.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
        crc2.save();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just recommand you to invert the content of if and else. Put
crc2.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
crc2.save();
at the beginning of your function and you should get what you're looking for.

```js
let ctx=can.getContext("2d");
let prevWidth=0;
let prevHeight = 0;

let drawBackgroundBig = () => {

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, prevWidth, prevHeight);
  ctx.save();
        
  let newHeight = parseInt(myRange1.value);
  // console.log(heightSlider.value);

  let newWidth = parseInt(myRange2.value);
  // console.log(widthSlider.value);

  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.save();
  
  prevWidth = newWidth;
  prevHeight = newHeight;
  
}
myRange1.onchange=()=>{drawBackgroundBig();}
myRange2.onchange=()=>{drawBackgroundBig();}
```

```html
<canvas id="can" height=300 width=300 ></canvas>
<div>
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" id="myRange1">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" id="myRange2">
</div>
```